# How to capture multiple Canvas with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below with 3 divs i'm using the library `html2canvas`to capture and download the `yellow div` but what i'm trying to accomplish is to try and capture the `yellow and black div` into one picture and download it. I have no idea if its possible to do accomplish it but any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture')).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 10px; background: pink">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 10px; background: black">
    <h4 style="color: white; ">Helloo world!</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="match-button" onclick="sendData();">capture</div>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library that you are using does not accept more than one DOM element. So, to achieve the result you want, you must wrap the two div's with a parent that will have the id `#capture` as the example:

```
  <div id="capture">
    <div style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
      <h4 style="color: #000; ">Helloo world!</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px; background: black">
      <h4 style="color: white; ">Helloo world!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ohh so this library don't allow me to capture multiple separated divs? Do you know any other libraries that can accomplish what i'm trying to achieve or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: With this library it's impossible. And what you are trying to do will have blank spaces between the div's in the images. This type of libraries prints the specified element. You can't print multiple elements in separate parts of the screen.